# multiply function

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation

I need to extract bit of a decimal number.
for example, y=52 (110100 to binary) and j=2..
so i need to return 1...
if j=3 return 0...

this is my function...

```
function int multiply(int x, int y) {

    var int tx;
    var int ty;

    let tx = x;
    let ty = y;

    let tx = Math.abs(x);
    let ty = Math.abs(y);

    var int shiftedX;
    let shiftedX = tx;

    var int result;
    let result = 0;

    var int i;
    let i = 0;
    while(i<16){
        if( i-th bit of ty = 1 )//pseudo code...
        {
            let result = result + shiftedX;
        }
        let shiftedX = shiftedX + shiftedX;
    }
    if(((x > 0) & (y < 0)) | ((x < 0) & (y > 0))){
        return -result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I wrote in the "if" pseudo code

How can i do this with really code??

Comment: Simple, you implement the pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jack appears to lack bitshifts, but that's OK, we can make the right mask in the same way as `shiftedX` is kept current (instead of doing `tx << i`), like this:

```
var int shiftedX;
let shiftedX = x;
var int mask;
let mask = 1;
var int i;
let i = 0;
while(i < 16){
    if((y & mask) = mask)
    {
        let result = result + shiftedX;
    }
    let shiftedX = shiftedX + shiftedX;
    let mask = mask + mask;
    let i = i + 1;
}
```

You can leave out the `abs` stuff and the sign-fix on the end (as long as you leave them *both* out), signed and unsigned multiplication are the same thing.

Comment: thanks for the answer but are you sure that I don't have to take care of tje sign???

Comment: @user3460154 pretty sure, but you could try it both ways and see if it makes any difference

Comment: Hi @harold for the **divide function** you think that I don't have care of the sign? like **multiply**?
Thanks

Comment: @benhi for divide it does matter, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

**At the time of answering this question, it was tagged under C or C++...**

---

First of all, get rid of the following symbols (as they are not part of the language):

```
- function
- var
- let
```

As to your question, you can use the following piece of code:

```
for (i=0; i<16; i++)
{
    if ((ty>>i) & 1)
    {
        result += shiftedX;
    }
    shiftedX <<= 1;
}
```

Comment: sorry it was a mistake, I corrected it.
if (i-th bit of ty = 1)

Comment: `shiftedX + shiftedX` is OK

Comment: @harold: Of course it's OK, but I get the feeling that OP wants something else out of that.

Comment: Well this way it ends up multiplying so what's the problem? Also, the last part is a way to correct the signs (that are broken due to the abs in the beginning)

Comment: @harold: No problem. I admit that I did not look into the purpose of the code, only into the specific question at hand. And since there are quite a few "puzzles" within this code, I assumed that it might be one of them (as it would be a lot more trivial to write `shiftedX = shiftedX * 2`, even for a "very" beginner).

Comment: I can't used the operator * so I instead of **shiftedX * 2** I need to do **shiftedX + shiftedX**

Comment: @barakmanos Thanks for your answer.
Can you give me more explication of this line 'if ((ty>>i) & 1)'??

Comment: @user3460154: What exactly is your question? "How can I implement the pseudo code below, using only what's already in it"??? If you don't know some keyword or operator of the language (which you originally tagged your question under, C or C++ if memory serves correctly), then you should **get to know it instead of refraining from using it**. The `>>` is a right-shift operator, and the `<<` is a left-shift operator.

Comment: @barakmanos I am sorry it isn't c or c++ language (it was a mistake)...
The language is Jack create for the Nand2tetris book.

Comment: @user3460154: You keep changing your question, which makes the answer irrelevant!!! **In particularly, removing the C/C++ tag from your question has made it completely pointless, as you are essentially asking to convert pseudo code into real code, without specifying the actual language!!!** In addition to that, I don't understand the meaning of "the language is Jack create for the Nand2tetris book" (and I doubt that anyone else does). In any case, the above answer can also be used under several other languages, such as Java, C#, Javascript, and probably a few more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the moderators at the official Nand2Tetris help forum
    http://nand2tetris-questions-and-answers-forum.32033.n3.nabble.com/
Be sure to check and post there for help, too.

Regarding signed versus unsigned multiplication:

When you multiply two 16-bit numbers, you get a 32-bit result.  The bottom 16-bits of this result is the same whether the numbers you are multiplying are signed or unsigned; only the upper 16-bits are different.

Since the Math.multiply routine only returns 16 bits, you don't need to worry about the signs of x and y.